# Issue with multiple API hits with each action in react-admin

Tags: node.js, django, react-admin

In my react-admin application, I'm sending two api hits for each create action and I'm not sure why.

[Network Tab Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meFse.png)

I have the django REST framework backend running as well, could this be the issue?

Comment: Are the duplicates the same request type or is one an OPTIONS request?

Comment: With the exception of a preflighted request for CORS, we'll need more information about your situation before being able to suggest possible solutions. What have you tried? Is there any particular area that you've narrowed down to be the source of the problem? Is there anything that you've eliminated as the problem?

Comment: It looks like they are identical requests sent twice on each PUT and GET request.

Comment: I've tried taking out all requests but one and it still occurs. I'm pretty stumped on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Your API is probably on another domain than the HTML page, so your browser sends a CORS preflight request to the server with the HTTP `OPTIONS` verb before sending a `GET` or a `PUT`. This is absolutely normal and there is nothing you can do to prevent it - apart from putting your API and your webapp on the same domain.

More information about CORS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Isn't this considered a simple request and not trigger a CORS preflight? And it not (to clarify), the only way to prevent this is with hosting the API on the same domain?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "simple" request. As long as a web page makes an AJAX request on another domain than its own, the browser checks with that domain first that it allows cross-domain requests using the famous CORS preflight request. And yes, the only way to prevent this is to put both the web page and the API it calls on the same domain.

Comment: Also, could this be because of race conditions from react-final-form and not react-form?